# как вызвать suspend функцию из Сервиса Андроид?

Tags: kotlin, android-service, coroutine

Обычно фрагменты или вьювмодели дают нам scope,

```
viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ***suspend...***
        }
 }
```

есть ли подобное в Сервисах или как вызвать suspend функцию из сервиса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно подключить библиотеку `"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"` и наследоваться от `LifecycleService`, тогда появится свойство `lifecycleScope`. Либо можно создать свой `CoroutineScope`:

```
class MyService : Service() {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate)

    override fun onDestroy() {
        scope.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```